# Как преобразовать структуру к другому типу?

Tags: c++, преобразование-типов

Есть `си` библиотека, в нем есть структура `typedef struct {} CStruct;`. Хочу иметь возможность преобразовывать его к другому типу не меняя исходники. Как это можно сделать?

---

**UDP**: Упаковать в другую структуру не всегда удобно + нужно много доп кода писать, вместо одной функции. Можно ли сделать лучше?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
// си структура, которую не трогаем
typedef struct {
    int a;
    double b;
} CStruct;

struct CppStruct {
    CStruct& d;
    CppStruct(CStruct& s) : d(s) {}
    operator CStruct() const {
        return d;
    }
    operator std::string() const {
        std::stringstream s;
        s << "(" << std::to_string(d.a) << ", " << std::to_string(d.b) << ")";
        return s.str();
    }
};

void someFunc(CStruct c) {
    cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
}

int main()
{
    CStruct t {2, 3.14};
    CppStruct tCpp(t);
    string s0 = CppStruct(t);   // не удобно
    string s1 = tCpp;           // удобно
    cout << s0 << endl << s1 << endl;
    cout << t.a << endl;        // удобен
    cout << tCpp.d.a << endl;   // не удобно
    someFunc(t);                // удобно
    someFunc(tCpp);             // удобно
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: судя по коду, Вы хотите скопировать, а не преобразовать.

Comment: @KoVadim читал близкую тему "`Перегрузка операций преобразования типов данных`", вот только нужно что бы саму структуру не трогали.

Comment: тогда в "принимающей структуре" просто напишите конструктор, который принимает целевую структуру единственным значением.

Comment: @KoVadim `std::string(CStruct s) {
    return std::string("CStruct");
}` так? тоже ошибка

Comment: я теперь понял, что Вы хотите. прям так объявить operator нельзя, а сам std::string так просто не поменять. Но если Вы скажете, какую задачу решаете, возможно будет более простое решение.

Comment: хочется с Си библиотекой работать как с с++. что бы вместо `CStruct2String(t)`, было либо `string s = t`, либо `string s = t.toString()`

Comment: тогда просто заверните си структуру в свою. Если дополнительных переменных в ней не будет, накладные расходы минимальны

Comment: @KoVadim обновил пример. Больше нет вариантов? если так то удобнее `CStruct2String` использовать

Comment: можно вот так написать `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const CStruct& cs)
{
    os << '(' << cs.a << ", " << cs.b << ')';
    return os;
}` и тогда будет работать вот так `std::cout << t;`